# Constructor injection in mapstruct when there is an abstract class extends

Tags: java, dependency-injection, abstract-class, mapstruct

I have recently started using Mapstruct as part of my work and finding this really useful

I am having an issue when I use mapstruct in an abstract class which extends an parent class

Here is some sample code

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Parent{
  private final ServiceA serviceA;
  private final ServiceB serviceB;
  
.....

}
```

Above parent, class is existing and used by a number of other components( extends it and uses it)

I have this abstract class where I am trying to maintain the mapper

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public abstract Child extends Parent implements XXX {
  
  private final ServiceA;
  
  public Child(ServiceA serviceA, ServiceB serviceB){
    super(serviceA,serviceB);
    this.serviceA=serviceA;
  }

  @Mapper
  ....
  
}
```

Above abstract child class extends from Parent and when I try to invoke a constructor based injection, the map struct doesn't allow this and expects a default no-args constructor to be present in the child class which is not possible (since parent class has a dependency on Service A and Service B)

I was trying to search for a solution and came across this thread, https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2257

I don't want to use composition to add Parent in child

But I think even setter injection is not going to help my situation. any thoughts/inputs on this ? Would really appreciate your help